# Decrement oracle sequence when an exception occurred

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I try to insert a new record in my database using pl/sql, so first of all I generate a new sequence like so:

```
select my_seq.nextval into seqId from dual;
```

And then i try to insert a new record using the generated seqId like this :

```
insert into myTable (id) values seqId ;
```

But when an error occurred during the insertion I want to decrement my sequence in an exception block. Does anyone have an idea please?

Comment: *Why* do you want that? What you "want" makes absolutely no sense; "wanting" it suggests that you don't understand how primary keys are supposed to work in a relational database. There is absolutely no valid reason to want "no gaps" in the sequence of id's.

Comment: @mathguy let's say that my actual sequence is 20  and i have a record with the id 20 , when my plsql code is executued first of all select my_seq.nextval is executed so my sequence is 21 right now and let's say that my insert query failed  my sequence stay at 21 , and when i executed my procedure again and my all works fine my new record will have 22 as id, like that i will have a record with id 20 and an other with id 22 but i don't want to have a jump of ids that's why i wanted to decrement the sequence if an exception is occured.

Comment: As mathguy said, when generating IDs for a primary key, it should not make a difference if they are sequential or not. If the IDs not being sequential is breaking your PL/SQL code, then you need to rework your PL/SQL code. Please share the problematic code if that is the issue.

Comment: In addition to all the other comments, you need to consider how this works in real-world multi-user environment.  Session A gets sequence 21. Then session B gets sequence 22.  Now session A wants to roll the sequence back.  But session B is just fine with sequence 22.

Comment: Let's examine a consequence if you actually implemented this. Now keep in mind **sequences are shared objects**.  UserA runs their process and gets seq_no 21, incrementing next_val to 22. Now your process gets seq_no 22, incrementing next_val to 23. and your process inserts id 22. At this point userA process has an exception, decrementing next_val to 22.  Your process continues and needs another seq_no, so you get next_val 22 and increment to 23. Then you insert and get "dup_val_on_index" exception - and you have no way of finding it. And what is the next_val now?  How well does your app run.

Comment: Other real world considerations: 1) sequences often need to cache a range of values in order to keep up with user demand. If something happens, like a database restart, any cached but unused values are lost. The next time values are cached, they will start from where the previous cache left off, even if not all of the values in the range were used. 2) In a RAC situation, each instance will have a separate cache with it's own values... Forcing the sequence to always increment by 1 is not scalable at all, let alone the idea of having no gaps.

Comment: Not recommended, expensive operation. 
Can take the max(id) from the table into a variable and add 1 to it. Then pass it as the insert value.

Comment: Won't work in a multi-user environment, @sandyv. Sooner or later two (or more) users will fetch the same MAX value, add 1 to it and only the first who commits will be able to insert a row. Everyone else will fail because of unique constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not decrement after the sequence is incremented (A sequence is either incremented or decremented not both) or reinitialize the sequence (start with ...) in Oracle. There is no way of doing that. Hope this helps.

However, if you want to continue this absurdity you can try this **but you need to initialize your sequence first which is myseq.nextval;**
then you can first try to insert currval and if succeeds then you can increment your sequence otherwise sequence will have its previous value.

```
Declare 
currval pls_integer;
inc pls_integer;
Begin

select seq.currval into currval from dual;

insert into myTable (id) values (currval) ;
select seq.nextval into inc from dual;

Exception
when others then
do the exception handling;
end;
```

Comment: This won't work because - in order to use CURRVAL - you first have to fetch NEXTVAL. Therefore, your code will fail with `ORA-08002: sequence SEQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session`

Comment: " but you need to initialize your sequence first which is myseq.nextval;" you did not read completely

Comment: So true! I read *code*, not *words*. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

As you were already told, you shouldn't be doing this at all. Anyway, here's how you *might* do it.

Sample table and a sequence:

```
SQL> create table mytable (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

Procedure which inserts `seq.nextval` into `mytable` and decrements the sequence in a case of a failure. I'm doing it in a simplest way - dropping it and recreating with the `start` parameter set to the last fetched value *minus 1*. `DBMS_OUTPUT` calls are here just to show what's going on in the procedure.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2    seqid number;
  3  begin
  4    seqid := seq.nextval;
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Sequence number to be inserted = ' || seqid);
  6
  7    insert into mytable(id) values (seqid);
  8
  9  exception
 10    when others then
 11      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
 12      execute immediate 'drop sequence seq';
 13      execute immediate 'create sequence seq start with ' || to_char(seqid - 1);
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's test it: this should insert `1`:

```
SQL> exec p_test;
Sequence number to be inserted = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from mytable;

        ID
----------
         1
```

So far so good. Now, I'll manually insert `ID = 2` so that the next procedure call violates unique constraint:

```
SQL> insert into mytable values (2);

1 row created.
```

Calling the procedure again:

```
SQL> exec p_test;
Sequence number to be inserted = 2
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C007547) violated

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OK; procedure *silently* completed. It didn't insert anything, but it decremented the sequence:

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

        ID
----------
         1        --> populated with the first P_TEST call
         2        --> populated manually

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1        --> sequence is decremented from 2 to 1
```

If I delete the offending `ID = 2` and try again:

```
SQL> delete from mytable where id = 2;

1 row deleted.

SQL> exec p_test;
Sequence number to be inserted = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from mytable;

        ID
----------
         1
         2

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Right; kind of *works*, but it's not worth the pain.

Besides, as you commented that there are 20 rows in a table. What will you do if someone deletes row #13. Will you decrement all values between #14 and 20? What if that's a primary key, referenced by some foreign keys?

Seriously, don't do it.

Comment: What about using the identity column, I don't know very much about that topic.

Comment: In the background, identity column uses a sequence so that wouldn't be much of an improvement for what you wanted. Also, in order to use it, your database version must be 12c and above.